# Meaning of Quran 2:111 "Produce your proof"?

Tags: quran, tafseer, christianity, judaism

111. And they say: "None
     Shall enter Paradise unless
     He be a Jew or a Christian."
     Those are their (vain) desires.
     Say: "Produce your proof
     If ye are truthful."
112. Nay,—whoever submits
     His whole self to God
     And is a doer of good,
     He will get his reward
     With his Lord;
     On such shall be no fear,
     Nor shall they grieve.

Please answer what is this proof? Where is this proof to come from?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any. The whole point of these ayat are as a challenge to the people making these baseless claims without any proof to back them up.